# How to add MacPorts to php-fpm's PATH in MacOSX

Tags: php, macos, shell, environment-variables, macports

The problem is actually in PHP script run by `php-fpm` 5.6 which is installed from `MacPorts`.

PHP code `system('echo $PATH')`
when run by `php-fpm` it returns

> /usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:.

when run by php `cli` in `bash` it returns

> /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin

`system` executes command in `sh` not `bash`, but `MacPorts` adds

> export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"

to `~/.profile` and `php-fpm` is run by `nobody` not my current user, so that export does not affect `php-fpm`.

I know I can add that PATH from export to `/etc/profile` or to `/etc/paths`.
But which way in safer in case of `MacPorts`. I don't want to break native `OS X` functionality or cause conflicts with `MacPorts`.

**EDIT**:

changing `/etc/profile` or `/etc/paths` does not actually help, `system` still does not see programs in `/opt/local/bin/`:

> sh: mysql: command not found

Comment: How is php-fpm started in your environment? If you're using a launchd plist to start the webserver that talks to php-fpm, you may have to add the path settings in this plist. Also note that changes to `/etc/paths` will usually require a re-login to take effect.

Comment: @neverpanic I use `sudo port load php56-fpm` which I guess in its turn uses plist. and I restarted the system before posting the question.

Comment: Yeah, I think in this case you would have to specify the environment manually in the plist file.

Comment: @neverpanic so it is a macports bug if its not specified there for me upon installation/update, right?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path (see what I did there?)

Editing `/etc/paths` is the solution, but you're not just looking for `/opt/local/bin/`. The `mysql` binary is (assuming MySQL 5.5) stored in `/opt/local/lib/mysql55/bin/mysql`. There are a number of such paths in MacPorts:

```
/opt/local/bin/
/opt/local/sbin/
/opt/local/apache2/bin/
/opt/local/lib/mysql55/bin/
/opt/local/lib/php/pear/bin/
```

Comment: mysql is in /opt/local/bin and fpm still does see it

Comment: What does `which mysql` tell you? Seems odd that MacPorts would put it in a different location on your system.

Comment: /opt/local/bin/mysql. it is a symlink to /opt/local/lib/mysql56/bin/mysql but who cares

Comment: The symlink is due to `sudo port select --set mysql mysql56`, which is a MacPorts feature.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked is setting `env[PATH]` in `/opt/local/etc/php56/php-fpm.conf` to the result of `echo $PATH`